# Best way to compare 2 similar strings?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Original Question:

> I have a lot of products with various names, I have two variations of
>   the names I need compared (Basically finding out if these two strings
>   are the same products). I don't want any false flags, does anyone have
>   recommendations on how I can achieve this?
>
> Here is a product example:
>
> `Canon 50mm f/1.2L` vs `Canon EF 50mm f/1.2L USM Lens`
>
> There are other variations, but this will be the typical difference.
>   Is there any easy functionality I could implement to get a certain
>   answer? Only thing I can think of is maybe splitting the strings and
>   comparing and say if x matches a, b, or c.

---

My original question was a bit vague. The end goal is to be able to compare two strings and see how similar they are - e.g. 0%, 50%, or 100% similar. In this scenario I am using lens products from different sources, they use similar names - however I have no product sku/id for proper comparison.

The [string score plugin](https://github.com/joshaven/string_score) has solved my issue, providing a value of how `similar` these products are.

Comment: define 'similar'

Comment: You need to classify how you define *"similar"* strings, along with how similar is similar enough. You all need to state the other variations. Without being specific this is a very difficult problem, as in asking for a Machine Learning approach that has a 100% accuracy.

Comment: This is not a trivial problem to solve. Even based on your example, it's not clear if you mean for both of those to be an equivalent product or not.

Comment: Only option I can see is splitting the string on the left into a string[] and then checking the string on the right if it contains each of the strings in the array. But I am not to sure if there is separate logic or requirements for them to be the same.Your shared example shows the right string containing everything the left string has but without the EF... which could be a different model?

Comment: Heck, *humans* can't do it with 100% accuracy, unless they have intimate knowledge of the state of the relevant industry. But you might get some mileage out of Google's diff-match-patch library. The details of what to do with the result are yours to experiment with.

Comment: One approach might be to split both strings into words then see if all the words of the shorter phrase are in the longer phrase (where "shorter" and "longer" are determined by the number of words).

Comment: Sorry guys, I made this post when I was a bit tired. The similar means same product but slightly different names. The string score package seems to fulfill my needs prettty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bioinformatics word and I believe in other domains, this kind of pattern matching/searching algorithm is called `fuzzy search`.

There is a nodeJS module called `string_score` for it. Essentially you feed the API with 2 pieces of string and it returns you a score of how similar they are.

**Example:**

```
var test = require('string_score');

var match_percent = "Canon EF 50mm f/1.2L USM Lens".score("Canon 50mm f/1.2L");
console.log("Match score= " + match_percent);
```

**Output:**

> Match score= 0.7938133874239354

Using the score as a baseline for comparison. You can say if it has a score of equip or over `80` then it is a match.

**More Example:**

```js
var score = 0;

score = "hello world".score("he");        
console.log("Match score => " + score);

score = "hello world".score("hel");
console.log("Match score => " + score);

score = "hello world".score("hell");
console.log("Match score => " + score);

score = "hello world".score("hello");
console.log("Match score => " + score);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/string_score/0.1.10/string_score.min.js"></script>
```

**References:**

String_score: https://github.com/joshaven/string_score

Comment: Can't believe I haven't found this before, thanks a ton. I tested a lot of products and it did perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about how would you recognize if two strings are the same product yourself, just by reading them.

Based solely on the examples you provided, it seems that the way to tell two strings representing a product are the same is if every word (a token separated by spaces) from the shorter string is contained in the longer string.

You might also want to ignore capitalization.

Something like this should work for the basic usage:

```js
const tokens = s => s.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/g);

const sameProducts = (s1, s2) => {

  const s1Tokens = tokens(s1);
  const s2Tokens = tokens(s2);

  const [shorterTokens, longerTokens] = s1Tokens.length > s2Tokens.length
    ? [s2Tokens, s1Tokens]
    : [s1Tokens, s2Tokens];

  return shorterTokens.every(st => longerTokens.includes(st));
}

console.log(
  sameProducts(
    'Canon 50mm f/1.2L',
    'Canon EF 50mm f/1.2L USM Lens'
  )
)
```

This code would have quadratic time complexity because the most expensive operation means that, for every token in the shorter string, you have to iterate through every token in the longer string.

A simple optimization would be to build a `Set<token>` from the longer string. This would make the operation linear because searching a set is `O(1)`.

```js
const tokens = s => s.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/g);

const sameProducts = (s1, s2) => {

  const s1Tokens = tokens(s1);
  const s2Tokens = tokens(s2);

  const [shorterTokens, longerTokens] = s1Tokens.length > s2Tokens.length
    ? [s2Tokens, s1Tokens]
    : [s1Tokens, s2Tokens];

  const longerTokensSet = longerTokens.reduce((s, t) => {
    s.add(t);
    return s;
  }, new Set());

  return shorterTokens.every(st => longerTokensSet.has(st));
}

console.log(
  sameProducts(
    'Canon 50mm f/1.2L',
    'Canon EF 50mm f/1.2L USM Lens'
  )
)
```

Now you have to consider, do **all** tokens have to match? Maybe only tokens corresponding to the brand and focal-length have to match.

If this is the case, you might also want to validate both strings while parsing them and return `false` immediately if the product strings are invalid.

Here's a rough idea:

```js
const productSet = new Set(['canon'])
const focalLengthsSet = new Set(['50mm']);

const isMeaningful = t => productSet.has(t) || focalLengthsSet.has(t);

const meaningfulTokens = s => s.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/g).filter(isMeaningful);

const validTokens = (tokens, s) => {
  const valid = tokens.length === 2;  // <-- could do better validation here
  console.assert(valid, `Missing token(s) in ${s}`);
  return valid;
}

const sameProducts = (s1, s2) => {

  const s1Tokens = meaningfulTokens(s1);
  if (!validTokens(s1Tokens, s1)) { return false; }
  
  const s2Tokens = meaningfulTokens(s2);
  if (!validTokens(s2Tokens, s2)) { return false; }

  const [shorterTokens, longerTokens] = s1Tokens.length > s2Tokens.length
    ? [s2Tokens, s1Tokens]
    : [s1Tokens, s2Tokens];

  const longerTokensSet = longerTokens.reduce((s, t) => {
    s.add(t);
    return s;
  }, new Set());

  return shorterTokens.every(st => longerTokensSet.has(st));
}

console.log(
  sameProducts(
    'Canon 50mm f/1.3',
    'Canon EF 50mm f/1.2'
  )
)

console.log(
  sameProducts(
    'Canon 50mm f/1.3',
    'Canon EF f/1.2' // <-- missing focal length
  )
)
```

Now you could consider does every focal length correspond to every product or is it more product-specific?

Do tokens contain logic that explicitly depends on previously matched tokens?

All of the above are just basic approaches and techniques you could use but the actual solution would heavily depend on your exact circumstances.

---

A common algorithm for measuring string similarity is called the [Levenstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

> The Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits (insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one word into the other.

This algorithm would allow you to perhaps match the strings directly if you edit distance threshold is strict enough (although this could provide false positives) or you could even account for misspelled products for example when comparing individual tokens by making sure they are within a specific edit distance from one another.

Comment: Regarding: "*you have to iterate through every token in the longer string*". That's not necessarily correct. The algorithm for *every* is implementation dependent, so it might build an index and do a binary lookup. Maybe it's just me, but all that use of *const* with arrow function expressions makes the code harder to read. `s.split(/\s+/g).map(t => t.toLowerCase())` would be more efficient as `s.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/)`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG sure but that is, as you've said, an implementation detail. It shouldn't really be relied on. The complexities I've given are the worst algorithmic limits, not implementation specific constraints which depend on the physical system. As far as arrow function, I don't really mind either way in terms of readability but if somebody else suggests, I don't mind changing it. Added your suggestion for the lowerCase approach.